# Why am I not prompted to 'Keep notes on iPhone' when I disable Notes in iCloud settings?

Tags: iphone, icloud, notes.app

Other things like Contacts, Reminders, Calendars, and Safari data all prompted me to 'keep data on iPhone' when I toggled them off in iCloud settings, but not Notes!

I want to keep my notes on my iPhone when iCloud is disabled.

Comment: Just for clarification, you do actually have iCloud notes on your iPhone and not just notes stored in "On my iPhone"?

Answer (score 1):

It's either a bug or by design. My iDevices do the same.

You could try moving them to a different account using the notes app on the Mac, if you have access to that. That wouldn't solve your problem completely though.